# ASP.NET databound dropodownlist set value with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors, html-select

I'm trying to select the value of a DropDownList of a FormView through jQuery.
The code I'm using is not working but I cannot understand why:

```
$("input[id$='_ddlwidget']").val(_data[0]);
```

Debugging it shows that the line is executed without problem but the DropDownList item is not changed.

The DropDownList is defined in this way:

```
<asp:FormView
   ID="_fvData"
   runat="server"
   DataKeyNames="id"
   DataSourceID="_sdsTable2"
   DefaultMode="Insert" Width="100%">
   <InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="_ddlwidget" runat="server" DataSourceID="_sdsTable1"
        DataTextField="text_field1" DataValueField="text_field2"
        AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("_field2")%>'>
   </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView
```

Comment: have you checked the id?  unless you changed it, asp.net auto-generates id's and they won't match in rendered markup.   You can use <% _ddlwidget.clientID %>  to get the id to reference in the aspx page or set the server side tag to static with ClientIDMode=static

Comment: Eric ... the javascript code wrote above works for all the fields 'generated' by asp.net  . Indeed if I debug the javascript code I got not error neither exceptions. If I had misspelled the id the object return from JQuery selection should be `null` and thus calling `.val()` will lead to exception.

Comment: it should also be null because a dropdown list isn't an "input", it's "select".  so you must have another input element that is called _ddlwidget.

Comment: hallo @Eric ... this's going to be a big mistery... now the code provided by johnnyRose is working. Regarding the value returned by `$("input[id$='_ddlwidget']")` I can certify that was not returning a `null` value.. and otherwise all `_ddl*` items in my code are DropDownList ... as you suggest anyway the problem was probably the id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data[0]` is a valid option for that DropDownList, just use the normal [jQuery id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
$('#_ddlwidget').val(_data[0]);
```

That should work just fine.

Comment: thnx but this wiill not work (I checked that) .. but probably I fooled you with my code please take a look at the asp.net code now, I think it's cleaner now..

Comment: Have you tried it? That's a pretty standard way to set a value in jQuery.

Comment: Yes I tried it... I will try to debug it trough IE but up to now I can certify that it's not working as expected the value is not changed (as it was not with my code).

Comment: Can you post your whole view? Including all the JavaScript?

Comment: the whole code is a little too large for this. What you need to know?

Comment: Anything relevant. It feels like the question is missing something. If the jQuery is on the same HTML file or called by that file, I'm not sure why the selector I provided wouldn't work.

Comment: The javascript code is in a separate file.. no problem to move it inside anyway.